# R-shiny app- DT package column information

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to create an R shiny app using the DT package. I would like to add information about the column header when the user toggles over it. Example: In "mtcars" data set, if a user toggles over 'mpg'column, they should be able to see a one-line definition for it.  I searched for solutions online but could not find any. I would genuinely be grateful to you for helping me with this.
Also, I would appreciate it if anyone could send me links to some beautiful DT related apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(DT)

headerCallback <- c(
  "function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  var tooltips = ['tooltip1','tooltip2','tooltip3','tooltip4','tooltip5'];",
  "  for(var i=0; i<5; i++){",
  "    $('th:eq('+i+')',thead).attr('title', tooltips[i]);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

datatable(iris, rownames = FALSE, 
          options = list(
            headerCallback = JS(headerCallback)
          )
)
```